# Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘Exception’ with message ‘DateTime::__construct():

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

how do I resolve this issue.

[this is my site](http://buddreambig.com/index.php)

this is the complete error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (03-22-2016) at
>   position 0 (0): Unexpected character' in
>   /home/budweiser/public_html/verify.php:13 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/budweiser/public_html/verify.php(13):
>   DateTime->__construct('03-22-2016') #1
>   /home/budweiser/public_html/verify.php(35): age('03-10-1991') #2
>   {main} thrown in /home/budweiser/public_html/verify.php on line 13

My code:

```
<?php
    //created date function
function age($dob){
    //echo $dob;
    $dob = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($dob));
    $date1 = new DateTime($dob);
    $date2 = new DateTime(date("m-d-Y"));
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    return $interval->y;
}

    //if a form is submitted do the following
if(array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){
    $mm = $_POST["date_"]["month"];
    $dd = $_POST["date_"]["day"];
    $yyyy = $_POST["date_"]["year"];

    $age = age($mm."-".$dd."-".$yyyy);
    //check age here
    if($age > 17){
                    //set cookie here and redirect here if you want
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["old_enough"] = true;
        header('Location: http://91.109.247.179/~buddreambig/index.php');

    }else{
                    //redirect here as well
        include("verify-age.html");
    }
} else {
    include("verify-age.html");
}
?>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

**NEW ERROR**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (1970197019701970-JanJan-ThuThu) at position 7 (0): Double date
>   specification' in /home/budweiser/public_html/verify.php:11 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/budweiser/public_html/verify.php(11):
>   DateTime->__construct('197019701970197...') #1
>   /home/budweiser/public_html/verify.php(35): age('--') #2 {main} thrown
>   in /home/budweiser/public_html/verify.php on line 11

```
<?php

    //created date function

function age($dob){

    //echo $dob;

    $dob = date("YYYY-MM-DD", strtotime($dob));

    $date1 = new DateTime($dob);

    $date2 = new DateTime("now");

    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);

    return $interval->y;

}



    //if a form is submitted do the following

if(array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){

    $MM = $_POST["date_"]["month"];

    $DD = $_POST["date_"]["day"];

    $YYYY = $_POST["date_"]["year"];



    $age = age($YYYY."-".$MM."-".$DD);

    //check age here

    if($age > 17){

                    //set cookie here and redirect here if you want

        session_start();

        $_SESSION["old_enough"] = true;

        header('Location: http://buddreambig.com/');



    }else{

                    //redirect here as well

        include("verify-age.html");

    }

} else {

    include("verify-age.html");

}

?>
```

Comment: Please post you code so we can help you out

Comment: oh yes.
[this is my code](http://codepad.org/4h8jdVgK)

Comment: Please post your code ***here***.

Comment: i cant  as it says, its too long. thats why I posted it online and shared the link above

Comment: I just updated my code, still no luck.

Comment: You do understand that `1970197019701970-JanJan-ThuThu` is nonsense and that the exception is telling you as much...!?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `age()` function with below. 
[Read more original post](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
function age($dob){
    //echo $dob;
    $date1 = new DateTime($dob);
    $date2 = new DateTime("now");
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    return $interval->y;
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I tried your solution, but its still giving the same solution.

Comment: I changed $date2 = new DateTime(date("m-d-Y")); to $date2 = new DateTime("now");

and I also reversed the date sequence dd-mm-yyyy to YYYY-MM-DD

still, I am getting the same error.

[see here](http://codepad.org/bjGmH5FI)

Comment: Remove ` $dob = date("YYYY-MM-DD", strtotime($dob));` as i have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is now resolved.

I just removed the first line of my function

thanks everyone.

Comment: Pls, update answer with correct code. which line you have removed exactly?